# Calculation on dynamic data in React

Tags: reactjs

This array can be fetched by .map in return()

```
[
    {
        "a": "3",
        "Count": "3",
        "b": "299.98999786376953",
        "c": "30",
        "d": "30"
    },
    {
        "a": "9",
        "Count": "1",
        "b": "99.98999786376953",
        "c": "10",
        "d": "9"
    }
]
```

I want to apply formulas on it like:

```
a = a/Count;
b = (b/(Count*10))*100;
c = (c/(Count*10))*100;
d = (d/(Count*10))*100;
Also find e = (a+b+c+d)/4;
```

then display them in each table row's data using .map

I tried npmjs.com/package/react-equation, it can do calculations directly in return() however don't fetch dynamic variables of array inside return(). I also tried creating a function outside return add(a,b){return a+b) and calling it inside return(), neither do it work and tried some other methods as well.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Sounds great, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code that can help you continue your work. It uses `map` to transform your string array to float array and also return the new calculated objects

```js
const array = [
    {
        "a": "3",
        "Count": "3",
        "b": "299.98999786376953",
        "c": "30",
        "d": "30"
    },
    {
        "a": "9",
        "Count": "1",
        "b": "99.98999786376953",
        "c": "10",
        "d": "9"
    }
]

const newArray = array.map(obj => {
 const a = parseFloat(obj.a) / parseFloat(obj.Count);
 const b = (parseFloat(obj.b)/(parseFloat(obj.Count) * 10)) * 100
 const c = (parseFloat(obj.c)/(parseFloat(obj.Count) * 10)) * 100
 const d = (parseFloat(obj.d)/(parseFloat(obj.Count) * 10)) * 100
 return { a, b, c, d, e: (a+b+c+d)/4}
})

console.log(array, newArray)
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know you could that!

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to do similar on server side before fetching data to client side. This worked great on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really use `map` because you're doing different calculations for `a` and for `b`,`c`,`d` and for `e`, and also because the calcultions on `a` depends on value of `Count`. You could just define a function that accepts the entire object and performs the calculations like so:

```
const performCalculations = (obj) => {
  obj.a = obj.a / obj.Count;
  obj.b = (obj.b/(obj.Count*10))*100;
  obj.c = (obj.c/(obj.Count*10))*100;
  obj.d = (obj.d/(obj.Count*10))*100;
  obj.e = (obj.a + obj.b + obj.c + obj.d)/4;
  return obj;
}
```

Edit: you can use map see @Apostolos answer

Comment: he **can** use map

Comment: @Apostolos - if it is possible to use map, could you provide some code to show me how it's possible? I'm really curious too, I'd love to see it :)

Comment: i didnt answer because as other ppl commented, he should provide what he has done so far, but ok i'll post an answer in a couple of minutes!

Comment: check my answer. i guess he needs sth like this.